# How can I connect a Tomcat server in a Virtual Machine with Netbeans on the Host machine?

Tags: tomcat, netbeans, virtual-machine, vmware

I have a VMware Workstation machine running a terminal-only Ubuntu, which contains an Apache Tomcat server. The server is running and I can access it through the Host using the web browser, but I need to connect Netbeans (on the Host machine) to the Tomcat server. The problem is that I don't know what to type in Server Location in the following screenshot:
[image: netbeans server setup]

The server, on the virtual machine is running on `/usr/share/tomcat10`

Thanks in advance.

I have tried typing the server IP, the location of the server, and none worked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If Netbeans is expecting a directory you can not connect it to a virtual machine out of the box. The virtual machine has its own filesystem, invisible to the host. Use VMWare [to share the path](https://docs.vmware.com/en/VMware-Workstation-Pro/17/com.vmware.ws.using.doc/GUID-D6D9A5FD-7F5F-4C95-AFAB-EDE9335F5562.html) of Tomcat inside the virtual to machine to a path in the host machine that Netbeans can use.